# Postgres - substring from the beginning to the second last occurrence of a char within a string

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I need to retrieve the bolded section of the below string . This value is in a column within my Postgres database table.

**SEALS_LME_TRADES_MBL**_20220919_00212.csv

I tried to utilize the functions; substring, reverse, strpos but they all have limitations. It seems like regex is the best option, however I was not able to do it.

Essentially I need to substring from **beginning** till the **second last '_'**. I do not want the date and sequence number along with the file extension at the end.

The closes regex I managed to get is: ^(([^*]**){4})
https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This look a little wonky but how about this?

```
select substring ('SEALS_LME_TRADES_MBL_20220919_00212.csv', '^(.+)_[^_]+_[^_]+')
```

Translation

```
^     from the beginning
(.+)  any characters (capture and return this value), followed by
_     an underscore, followed by
[^_]+ one or more non-underscores, followed by
_     an underscore, followed by
[^_]+ one or more non-underscores
```

Regex greediness will cause any incidental underscores to be captured in the initial string.

Technically speaking the last portion (one or more non-underscores) can probably be omitted.

Comment: I'd anchor the regex at the end as well, just for extra paranoia: `'^(.+)_[^_]+_[^_]+$'`.

Comment: will this work if the file name starts having one additional word? I want to future proof the formula by figuring how to remove the end part (date, sequence# and file extension) while keeping everything before that.

Comment: @Achilles -- absolutely.  The greediness of regex will ensure that this will scale and only omit everything past the second to last underscore.  For example:  `select substring ('you_can_learn_a_lot_of_things_from_a_flower_20220919_00212.csv', '^(.+)_[^_]+_[^_]+')`.  If it was a predictable, fixed number, that would have been much easier!